# Can we evaluate training data-set using jackknife cross validation in Weka?

Tags: weka

I want to evaluate training data-set using jackknife cross validation in Weka. Can we evaluate by jackknife cross validation?

Answer (score 0):

Leave one out cross-validation should work if you specify n-fold, where n is your number of instances (rather than the default 10-fold).